# To be exact this is the error I'm seeing "NameError: name 'Solution' is not defined ret = Solution().containsDuplicate(param_1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    nums.sort()

    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/.   I don't know where my fault is, it won't run my test examples and shows me this error on my LeetCode

Comment: The leetcode example is for a class. Based on what you wrote in the for loop, I think you're conflating the class method with a function. But your code is some mutant version of a class and function. If you want to stick with the function, you don't need self.